# Loading base64 images through File API blocks DOM

Tags: javascript, fileapi

I'm selecting some images in an input field, than I insert it into the DOM into `img` tags. Works fine, but I'm showing a simple SVG loader which doesn't animating. It shows up, but no rotation. In other cases the loader animates well. How should I prevent DOM blocking in this case?

Comment: Can you create stacksnippets, or jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use some of CSS3 animation, for example, just find in google "css3 animation spinner", it is working without blocking.